# How do I create a global rakefile on Windows 7?

Tags: ruby, rake

I want to be able to create a rakefile on Windows 7 that I can call with the `rake -g <taskname>` or `rake --system <taskname>` command.  Where do I save the rakefile?  I've tried creating a Rake directory under my user directory (c:\users\me\rake), but when I call `rake -g hello_world`, rake errors out saying it doesn't know how to build the `:hello_world` task, which makes me think it just can't see the rakefile.  Here's what my global rakefile looks like:

```
require 'rake'

desc "a hello world task"    
task :hello_world do    
  puts "hello from your global rakefile"    
end
```

Comment: if it doesn't know how to build the task, it means that rake see the rakefile. so show us your rakefile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out - turns out Rake expects global rakefiles to end in a ".rake" extension.  I changed the example above to this:

```
require 'rake'

desc "a hello world task"    
task :hello_world do    
  puts "hello from {__FILE__}"    
end
```

And saved it as "testing.rake" in my c:\users\me\rake\ directory.  I opened up a command prompt to a random directory and ran "rake -g hello_world" and got this output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>rake -g hello_world
(in C:/Windows/system32)
hello from C:/Users/me/Rake/testing.rake
```

Answer (score 1):

Rake looks for Rakefile in the current directory unless specified explicitly as in:

```
rake --rakefile C:\users\me\rake\[rakefile]
```

Comment: Yep, but I'm interested in the global option. On a mac or any *nix system, you can use "rake -g" to execute commands in rakefiles in a directory called ".rake" in your user folder.  I can get this to work on a mac, but I can't seem to get it to work on a windows box.

Comment: What version of ruby/rake are you on? Also in your question you say you created a "rake" folder, not a ".rake" folder.

Comment: ruby 1.9.2p180.  I've tried both "rake" and ".rake" folders, as well as putting the rakefile directly in my user folder.  None of these three approaches has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Rake on Windows looks for $HOME/Rake/*.rake if the target cannot be found locally.  If HOME is not set, then it will use c:\Users\me\Rake as the other responders have indicated.

But, if you happen to have HOME set (as I do, operating in a mixed Cygwin/Windows 7 world), now you know where rake will be expecting to find your global rake files.

Btw, I don't find it necessary to pass the -g flag; Rake seems happy to find the global definitions on its own.  I think the only case in which -g is warranted is if you need to be absolutely sure there is no rake task of the same name locally.